# Renumber a list of sequential files while retaining the rest of the filename

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a series that's not numbered by season, but by absolute order going from 0 to 150 or so. I want to renumber these files by season so that they are picked up properly in Plex. Here's a sample (first 5 files) of what the "Season 2" folder looks like currently:

```
'Show Name - 014 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv'
'Show Name - 015 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv'
'Show Name - 016 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv'
'Show Name - 017 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv'
'Show Name - 018 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv'
```

and so on.

As you can see, the season starts numbered at 14 instead of 1. First I use Nautilus' renaming tool to replace the `- 0` with `S02E`. Here's what it looks like now:

```
anon@anonpc:~/Downloads/sandbox$ ls
'Show Name S02E14 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv'
'Show Name S02E15 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv'
'Show Name S02E16 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv'
'Show Name S02E17 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv'
'Show Name S02E18 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv'
```

But I need the episode numbers to start with 01. This is the closest I came up with:

`for i in {14..18}; do mv Show\ Name\ S02E$i*.mkv Show\ Name\ S02E$((i-13))*; done`

But this doesn't work correctly:

```
mv: target 'Show Name S02E18 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv' is not a directory
```

Now it looks like this:

```
anon@anonpc:~/Downloads/sandbox$ ls
'Show Name S02E14 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv'
'Show Name S02E2*'
'Show Name S02E3*'
'Show Name S02E4*'
'Show Name S02E5*'
```

You can see that the first wildcard `*` worked for picking up the full file names, but then the rest weren't respected by `mv` when renumbering the files. Also, I have no idea why the first item in the list didn't get renamed.

I would like to know how I could renumber the files in the way outlined above while retaining the original filename on either side of the integer. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with the default bash shell. Thanks

Comment: I don't know exactly how to write it, but there are 2 good ways to do this. The `rename` script, or a PERL script. You could also use `awk` piped to `sed`. I can't be of more help.

Comment: Do you still have the original filenames?

Comment: It's not clear whether this question is about what command you should have used, or what command to use now that the filenames are messed up

Comment: @steeldriver It is obvious that this question is for the original filenames. It would have been too trivial if it was for the shorter messed up filenames. Most of the question talks about problems parsing the part of the filename that would have been lost (unrecoverable to any answer). Therefore, there is no doubt this question was for the original filenames, as confirmed by the asker's now-deleted comment under my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash globing only works for existing files. In this case, you can just use Bash prefix removal (`${variable#prefix_to_remove}`) to specify the rename destination you want:

```bash
prefix=Show\ Name\ S02E
for i in {14..18}; do
  x=("$prefix"$i*.mkv) # Use glob to find the original file with the title
  y="${x#*S02}" # Remove the constant show name part
  y="${y#* }" # Remove the variably unknown part by removing up to the next space
  mv "$x" "$prefix$((i-13)) $y" # Compose the destination
done
```

Test run:

```
home@daniel-tablet1:~/tmp$ ll
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E14 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv'
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E15 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv'
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E16 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv'
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E17 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv'
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E18 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv'
home@daniel-tablet1:~/tmp$ prefix=Show\ Name\ S02E; for i in {14..18}; do x=("$prefix"$i*.mkv); y="${x#*S02}"; y="${y#* }"; mv "$x" "$prefix$((i-13)) $y"; done
home@daniel-tablet1:~/tmp$ ll
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E1 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv'
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E2 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv'
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E3 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv'
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E4 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv'
.rw-rw-r-- 0 home 25 Jan 18:57 'Show Name S02E5 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the versioning sort option in either GNU `sort` or GNU `ls` with `rename` like so:

```
printf '%s\n' * | sort -V | rename -v -n 'our $i; ++$i; s/([^\d]+)([\d]+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)(.*\.mkv)/$1$2$3$i$5$6$7/'
```

... or so:

```
ls -v | rename -v -n 'our $i; ++$i; s/([^\d]+)([\d]+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)(.*\.mkv$)/$1$2$3$i$5$6$7/'
```

`([^\d]+)` is a capturing group for non-numerical and `([\d]+)` is for only-numerical and `$1`, `$2`, `$3` ... etc. are their reference numbers ... you may need to adjust those depending on characters patterns in your filenames.

**Notice** those will fail if your filenames have newline characters in them.

The `-n` option of `rename` is for dry-run mode (no actual file renaming happen on the filesystem) ... So, try those and if you agree with the output, then re-run again without the `-n` option of `rename` like this demonstration:

```
$ ls -v | rename -v -n 'our $i; ++$i; s/([^\d]+)([\d]+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)(.*\.mkv)/$1$2$3$i$5$6$7/'
Reading filenames from file handle (GLOB(0x559cb54612b0))
rename(Show Name S02E9 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E1 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv)
rename(Show Name S02E10 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E2 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv)
rename(Show Name S02E11 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E3 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv)
rename(Show Name S02E12 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E4 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv)
rename(Show Name S02E16 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E5 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv)
rename(Show Name S02E17 Episode Title 6 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E6 Episode Title 6 [480p] [x265].mkv)
rename(Show Name S02E20 Episode Title 7 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E7 Episode Title 7 [480p] [x265].mkv)
rename(Show Name S02E21 Episode Title 8 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E8 Episode Title 8 [480p] [x265].mkv)
rename(Show Name S02E50 Episode Title 9 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E9 Episode Title 9 [480p] [x265].mkv)
rename(Show Name S02E100 Episode Title 10 [480p] [x265].mkv, Show Name S02E10 Episode Title 10 [480p] [x265].mkv)
$
$
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:12 'Show Name S02E100 Episode Title 10 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E10 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E11 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E12 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E16 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:11 'Show Name S02E17 Episode Title 6 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:11 'Show Name S02E20 Episode Title 7 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:11 'Show Name S02E21 Episode Title 8 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:12 'Show Name S02E50 Episode Title 9 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E9 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv'
$
$
$ ls -v | rename -v 'our $i; ++$i; s/([^\d]+)([\d]+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)(.*\.mkv$)/$1$2$3$i$5$6$7/'
Reading filenames from file handle (GLOB(0x55d02a78c0a0))
Show Name S02E9 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E1 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv
Show Name S02E10 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E2 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv
Show Name S02E11 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E3 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv
Show Name S02E12 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E4 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv
Show Name S02E16 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E5 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv
Show Name S02E17 Episode Title 6 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E6 Episode Title 6 [480p] [x265].mkv
Show Name S02E20 Episode Title 7 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E7 Episode Title 7 [480p] [x265].mkv
Show Name S02E21 Episode Title 8 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E8 Episode Title 8 [480p] [x265].mkv
Show Name S02E50 Episode Title 9 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E9 Episode Title 9 [480p] [x265].mkv
Show Name S02E100 Episode Title 10 [480p] [x265].mkv renamed as Show Name S02E10 Episode Title 10 [480p] [x265].mkv
$
$
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:12 'Show Name S02E10 Episode Title 10 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E1 Episode Title 1 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E2 Episode Title 2 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E3 Episode Title 3 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E4 Episode Title 4 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:10 'Show Name S02E5 Episode Title 5 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:11 'Show Name S02E6 Episode Title 6 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:11 'Show Name S02E7 Episode Title 7 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:11 'Show Name S02E8 Episode Title 8 [480p] [x265].mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 يناير  26 10:12 'Show Name S02E9 Episode Title 9 [480p] [x265].mkv'
```

This has the benefit of automatically dealing with any arbitrary/varying numbering sequences and still rename them to sequential numbers starting from `1` and based on their original sorting state.

Comment: Is the last/third `([^\d]+)([\d]+)` pair necessary? Anyway, after staring for a few minutes, thanks to your answer, I think I finally managed to grok the `rename` script!

Comment: @DanielT No, they are not but, the more controlled and strict the regular expressions pattern is the less mistakes we get ... I based those on the given example names in the question to show just an example.

Comment: It might be simpler to capture the existing number and simply subtract 13 from it ex. `rename -n 's/S02E(\d+)/sprintf "S02E%02d", $1 -13/e' -- *.mkv` - that way no sorting is required

Comment: @steeldriver True to an extent but, what if the numbers are not actually sequential from 14 up i.e. `14,17,23 …` … and I prefer not to use `e` when I can and I recon that is justified :-)

Comment: I've finally learned some Perl and I've come back to say that your solution is way too needlessly complicated. The files could have been renamed much more simply with this: `rename 's/([\d]+)([^\d]+)\K([\d]+)/sprintf("%02d",$3-13)/e' *.mkv`. Why did you even bother capturing non-numerical characters first? There are so many things I don't understand why you did - but still, this answer did help me learn the syntax, so thanks for that